# NSCopying: Use of "zone"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My classes implement `NSCopying` like this:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone {
    MyClass *copy = [[MyClass allocWithZone: zone] init];

    // Copy instance variables

    return copy;
}

@end
```

That means the copy is allocated in the required memory zone. In case the object contains instance variables that need to be copied, too, e.g. mutable arrays, should I use their `copyWithZone:` message and pass the `zone` along, instead of just calling `copy`?

Additionally, if there are instance variables that I want to instantiate directly instead of copying an object, will I have to allocate those by using the `allocWithZone:` class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zone is obsolete - there's nothing special to do with it. If you copy your ivars also, you can safely ignore it and just call copy on them.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the common opinion, too. Is there any official documentation to back that up?

Comment: @waldrumpus You're welcome. I believe Apple's docs mention it (but it was a long time ago I messed with NSCopying, so it may no longer be there).